# What am I doing wrong with this array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Okay, trying to put together a numeric array and arrange it in ascending order. The more I look, the more I confuse myself. The alerts come up as "undefined." What am I overlooking?

```
var random = new Array();
function main() {
    generate();
    original();
    ascending(random);
}
function generate() {
    document.write("Here are 25 Random Numbers:<br><br>");
    for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        random[i] = document.write(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + ", ");
    }
}
function original() {
    var storage = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        storage += random[i] + ", ";
    }
    alert(storage);
}
function ascending(random) {
    var tempArray = random;
    var storage = "";
    random.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a - b
    });

    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        storage += tempArray[i] + ", ";
    }
    alert("ASCENDING- " + storage);
}
```

Comment: I see a variable and four functions. I don't see how you call any of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need for `document.write` (not sure what were you trying to achieve with it), this is enough:

```
random[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
```

Afterwards, if you need to convert it to a string for output, just join it:

```
random.join(",");
```

---

Here is your `generate` function:

```js
var random = [];

function generate() {
  document.write("Here are 25 Random Numbers:<br><br>");
  for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    random[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  }
}

generate();
var str = random.join(', ');
document.write(str);
```

---

Note: try to [avoid using document.write whenever you can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice).

Answer (score 2):

Take out your `document.write()` call in `generate()`, that prints a number out to your HTML document, just assign it directly to your array.  You're assigning the *result* of that print out to your array, which is definitely not what you want.